# Objective C - SecItemAdd has error:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (first time) and errSecDuplicateItem (second time)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I use this code http://wiki.effectiveprogramming.com/index.php?title=CocoaEncryption&redirect=no in my application to implement Login function. But I have a error method saveRSAPublicKey:

```
+ (BOOL)saveRSAPublicKey:(NSData*)publicKey appTag:(NSString*)appTag overwrite:(BOOL)overwrite {
    //Error here (when first call) - Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" -> crash
    OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   (id)kSecClassKey, kSecClass,
                                                   (id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, kSecAttrKeyType,
                                                   (id)kSecAttrKeyClassPublic, kSecAttrKeyClass,
                                                   kCFBooleanTrue, kSecAttrIsPermanent,
                                                   [appTag dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], kSecAttrApplicationTag,
                                                   publicKey, kSecValueData,
                                                   kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnPersistentRef,
                                                   nil],
                                                   NULL);   //don't need public key ref

    DebugLog(@"result = %@", [KeychainUtil fetchStatus:status]);

    if(status == noErr)
        return YES;
    else if(status == errSecDuplicateItem && overwrite == YES)
        return [CryptoUtil updateRSAPublicKey:publicKey appTag:appTag];

    return NO;
}
```

When I call `saveRSAPublickey` for first time, I can't create OSStatus and my application is crashed. 
When I call `saveRSAPublickey` for second time: status == `errSecDuplicateItem` and run  `[CryptoUtil updateRSAPublicKey:publicKey appTag:appTag]` -> success.

It's difficult to find this problem when debugging because it just only appear in new device ( have never been installed my app). Finally, I have found the error by the way: set new appTag before call saveRSAPublicKey. I see in system.log:

**Apr  6 12:30:29 MACs-MacBook-Pro securityd[4372]: unable to access hwaes key**

Please help me !!!
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `NULL` for the 2nd arg (where your result would come out), then you're not allowed to have a `Return Type Key` set when calling `SecItemAdd()` (change `kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnPersistentRef` to `kCFBooleanFalse, kSecReturnPersistentRef` or just delete it).

I submitted a bug report on this just now.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that publicKey or, more likely, appTag don't contain what you think they do.  Try logging them out.

Comment: I took too much to debug and I make sure: publicKey is correct. I have a "appTag" variable is const string. If I want to restore the error, I change value of "appTag" variable.

Comment: System log:
Apr  6 11:35:58 MACs-MacBook-Pro securityd[4301]: unable to access hwaes key
Apr  6 11:36:12 MACs-MacBook-Pro [0x0-0x13013].com.google.Chrome[176]: [176:-1272877056:12564130414539:ERROR:spdy_session.cc(1386)] Spdy stream closed: 6

Comment: @CodaFi, I apologize, twas my first Answer/comment so I wasn't aware of the differences.

Comment: @PhamVan If I understand you correctly appCode was of type (const char *) ?  If so, why would you expect it to respond to -dataUsingEncoding: ?

Comment: Thanks Jared Kipe. I tried replacing  **[appTag dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]**  with **appTag** but it didn't work (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

Comment: @PhamVan Right, my meaning was that NSDictionary expects key's and values' to be objects not just some random C string literal.

Comment: @PhamVan NSDictionary (probably) sends retain to every incoming objects and ["some string" retain] will certainly EXEC_BAD_ACCESS as would any other message as it is not an object.  By const string did you mean some NSString literal like @"some string"?  Try breaking your NSDictionary creation out from the other function and try to see if you can build a dictionary (and maybe iterate through it) without a crash.  If you can't then your SecItemAdd() call won't help matters.

Comment: @Jared Kipe- I try logging NSDictionary and as the result the NSDictionary has data.

Comment: `NSDictionary *dict;
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                (id)kSecClassKey, kSecClass,
                (id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, kSecAttrKeyType,
                (id)kSecAttrKeyClassPublic, kSecAttrKeyClass,
                kCFBooleanTrue, kSecAttrIsPermanent,
                [appTag dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], kSecAttrApplicationTag,
                publicKey, kSecValueData,
                kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnPersistentRef,
                nil];`

Comment: `for (id key in dict)
 {
     NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
            
   }`

Comment: ...[489:bc03] key: kcls, value: 0

...[489:bc03] key: type, value: 42

...[489:bc03] key: atag, value: <49565354 616731>

...[489:bc03] key: r_PersistentRef, value: 1

...[489:bc03] key: class, value: keys

...[489:bc03] key: perm, value: 1

...[489:bc03] key: v_Data, value: <30490241 00e5c7b5 05e43845 b337675b f8df97e4 1cc3c940 829e82a3 6a962c31 03ba0623 3ee34262 7af30be8 75e380bc 132ad8b8 894b716a 7e734788 add02091 75e82cc9 df020301 000100>