# What might be causing SecItemAdd or SecItemCopyMatching to fail?

Tags: ios, keychain, sskeychain

I'm using this method in order to retrieve a saved value (and using `SecItemAdd` to add it originally):

```
+ (NSData *)passwordDataForService:(NSString *)service 
        account:(NSString *)account error:(NSError **)error {

    CFTypeRef result = NULL;    
    NSMutableDictionary *query = [self _queryForService:service account:account];

    [query setObject:(__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue 
        forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
    [query setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne 
        forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &result);

    if (status != noErr && error != NULL) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kSSKeychainErrorDomain code:status 
            userInfo:nil];
        return nil;
    }

    return (__bridge_transfer NSData *)result;
}
```

This code is working fine for most users, but a small percentage of my users (< 1%) are experiencing results indicating that either the read or write here is failing. My code unfortunately swallows any errors (i.e. doesn't log them anywhere when they occur) so I can't tell why it's failing out in the world, and I can't reproduce the problem at all on any of my development devices.

**Does anyone know of any security/permissions settings that can be enabled on an iOS device that could cause `SecItemAdd` or `SecItemCopyMatching` to fail?** I've tried turning on passcode locking, but that seems to have no effect.

Comment: [Passing `NULL` for the 2nd arg in `SecItemAdd` fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038885/objective-c-secitemadd-has-errorexc-bad-access-first-time-and-errsecduplica/19319848#19319848) (crashes in fact) when you have `KSecReturnData` set as TRUE

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm experiencing a similar issue, where CopyMatching doesn't find something, but when I try to add something it says it already exists.

Comment: @WDUK: sorry, I don't even remember asking this question, or what I was working on at the time. I probably solved the problem by leaving it for somebody else to deal with.

Comment: @MusiGenesis No worries, I posted a question earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403734/keychain-item-reported-as-errsecitemnotfound-but-receive-errsecduplicateitem-o Fingers crossed someone sees it!